# UIPanGestureRecognizer and random colors

Tags: swift, uikit, uipangesturerecognizer

I have `panPerformed()` and `randomColors()` methods. When I drag my finger on the screen, view's color is changing very fast.

How to make background color change 3 times slower when using Pan Gesture?

```
func randomColors() -> UIColor {

    let r = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    let g = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0
    let b = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(255)) / 255.0

    return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
}

@IBAction func panPerformed(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {

        let changeX = (self.view?.center.x)!
        let changeY = (self.view?.center.y)!
        
        sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: changeX, y: changeY)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.randomColors()
    }
}
```

I add this code with minor corrections in terms of syntax (thanks @Duncan C):

```
     // Add some instance variables:
      var r: Int = 0
      var g: Int = 0
      var b: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Give your background view an initial color
    r = Int.random(in: 0...255)
    g = Int.random(in: 0...255)
    b = Int.random(in: 0...255)
    self.view.backgroundColor = currentColor()

    // Convert the r/g/b Int values to a UIColor
    func currentColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r)/255.0, green:  CGFloat(g)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(b)/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

    // Randomly change the input value by +/- 5
    func addOrSubtract(from: Int) -> Int {
    var result = from + Int.random(in: -5...5)

    // Don't let the new value go < 0 or > 255
    if result < 0 {
        result = 0
    } else if result > 255 {
        result = 255
    }
    return Int()
}

   // Adjust the r, g, and b values up or down a little.
    func randomizeColor() {
        r = addOrSubtract(from: r)
        g = addOrSubtract(from: g)
        b = addOrSubtract(from: b)
}

   @IBAction func panPerformed(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
        if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
            let changeX = (self.view?.center.x)!
            let changeY = (self.view?.center.y)!
        
            sender.view?.center = CGPoint (x: changeX, y: changeY)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
            if changeX + changeY > 5 {
                randomizeColor()
               // self.view.backgroundColor =   self.randomColours() - the previous code
                self.view.backgroundColor = currentColor()
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

When I drag my finger on screen view's color turn on black without changing colours. What is the reason? addOrSubtract()?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you have any ideas how to fix it? Please add what you tried and what doesn't work to the post

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your question: "for example 3 times slowly?" What does that mean? You mean change at 1/3 the current rate of change?

Comment: As I can understand you have to change the color of the view slowly, but currently it is not possible to work with your code as and when user start dragging `panPerformed ` gets called continuously. So, only the possibility is that playing with timestamp with respect to old color changed to the new color setting.

Comment: if you also what to consider the speed of the dragging then you can also play with the `sender.velocity(in: view)` or `sender.translation(in: view)` and do your calculations accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You are making up your own feature. There isn't really a "right way" since this is your creation.

If you don't want the colors to change suddenly, why not save the previous color, and add a very small random change to each color channel every few points of finger dragging? Something like this:

```
// Add some instance variables:
var r: Int = 0
var g: Int = 0
var b: Int = 0

func viewDidLoad() {
  // Give your background view an initial color
  r = Int.random(0...255)
  g = Int.random(0...255)
  b = Int.random(0...255)
  self.view.backgroundColor = currentColor() 
}

// Convert the r/g/b Int values to a UIColor
func currentColor() -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r)/255.0, green: CGFloat(g)/255.0, blue: CGFloat(b)/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

// Randomly change the input value by +/- 5
func addOrSubtract(from: Int) -> Int {
    var result = from + Int.random(-5...5)

    // Don't let the new value go < 0 or > 255
    if result < 0 {
        result = 0
    } else if result > 255 {
        result = 255
    }
}  

// Adjust the r, g, and b values up or down a little.
func randomizeColor() {
    r = addOrSubtract(from: r)
    g = addOrSubtract5(from: g)
    b = addOrSubtract5(from: b)
}

@IBAction func panPerformed(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        let changeX = (self.view?.center.x)!
        let changeY = (self.view?.center.y)!
        
        sender.view?.center = CGPoint (x: changeX, y: changeY)
        sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)

        // If the user move their finger by more than a few points, 
        // change the background color slightly
        if changeX + changeY > 5 {
            randomizeColor()
            self.view.backgroundColor = currentColor() 
        }
    }
}
```

(Think of the above as pseudo-code. It probably has a few syntax errors and might even be buggy. It's not meant to be copy/paste ready.)

Comment: I edited my code according to your post. Thanks. Could you please look through update in my question?